# Biblatex: Adding time information to "online" field and a label in front of url

Tags: biblatex, urls, online

I am trying to add some "time" information to my online-fields in `biblatex`. I tried to use the `note` entry, but that won't work as intended.
Right now I got the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    oneside, 
    12pt, 
    bibliography=totocnumbered, 
    listof=totocnumbered
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, urldate=comp, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{source}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space#1}



\begin{document}
Latex is science \parencite{stack}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the file `source.bib` looks like:

```
@online{stack,
    author = {Stack},
    title = {Why Latex is science},
    month = {april},
    year = 2012,
    url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2013-04-29},
    note = "14.44 Uhr",
}
```

This currently gives me the following output:

[image: Current output]

What I really need right now is this:

> Stack (2012): Why Latex is science,  URL: www.tex.stackexchange.com,
>   29.4.2013, 14.44 Uhr.

So basically:

- Add time information at the end
- Add "URL: "-label in front of the actual url
- change some periods to colon or comma

Any help is appreciated!

---

### Update 1

So I am almost there. The time is added (thanks to Guido). I only need some more `field formating`. The code part looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
oneside, 
12pt, 
bibliography=totocnumbered, 
listof=totocnumbered
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[]{url}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, urldate=comp, dateabbrev=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{source}
%\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
%    \DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{urltime}
%\end{filecontents}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{#1}    % Not sure with this one
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\bibstring{URL}\addcolon\addspace\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space#1\addcomma\addspace\printfield{urltime}}



\begin{document}
Latex is science \parencite{stack}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And here's a colorful visualization of the way it should be in the end:

[image: how it needs to be in the end]

Comment: You can add the image to your question, and remove the leading `!`. Then, other users with enough reputation can add the `!` back. And: Welcome!

Comment: Have you tried putting the time and the date in the same field?

Comment: Thank you mafp! Seems like I have enough reputation already.

Comment: @ADP: I just tried now, but I'm not so sure what the proper format for putting it into the same entry would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Modified answer for UPDATE 1**

It is better not to use `note`. Biblatex offers the opportunity to create new fields, so I would create a new field for the url time (`urltime`).

This can be done with

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblatex-dm.cfg}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal,skipout=false]{urltime}
\end{filecontents}
```

then for the formatting of the URL and related  information a possibility is to use the following format instructions:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\newline\bibstring[\MakeUppercase]{url}\addcolon\addspace\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urltime}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{%
  \iffieldundef{urlday}
    {}
    {\stripzeros{\thefield{urlday}}\adddot}%
  \iffieldundef{urlmonth}
    {}
    {\stripzeros{\thefield{urlmonth}}\adddot}%
  \printfield{urlyear}%
}

\renewbibmacro{url+urldate}{%
  \printfield{url}\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}
  \printurldate\addcomma\addspace
  \printfield{urltime}}
```

To change the standard punctuation, from `.` (dot) to `.` (comma), one can use

```
\renewcommand{\newunitpunct}{\adddot}
```

For the `.` after the year,

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma}
```

Finally to remove the month from the label, a possible solution is to use

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
```

Entries in the `.bib` files now can contain the new `urltime` field.

```
@online{stack,
    author = {Stack},
    title = {Why {\LaTeX} is science},
    month = {april},
    year = 2012,
    url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com},
    urldate = {2013-04-29},
    urltime = "14.44 Uhr",
}
```

Please notice how properly write LaTeX in a `.bib` file. In general it is best to enclose whole words in `{` `}` of single letters to preserve their capitalisation (and then kerning by enclosing the whole word).

[image]

Comment: Thank you Guido, adding the time worked this was. Only thing is, that I get the following warning now: 

LaTeX Warning: File `biblatex-dm.cfg' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.

Comment: @Goliathus It's normal once you've already run a LaTeX document containing that `filecontents` environment: the file doesn't get rewritten.

Comment: This happens on the second or successive run. You have to generate that file only once. You can remove the first snippet after it has been generated the first time. Alternatively load the `filecontents` package.

Comment: Wow Guido, thank you very much! Because of you, I finally got it the way I needed it to be. 
Furthermore, a nice experience to see how exact one can get in LaTeX. But yeah, it sure is a science that needs to be learned... :}